# How to get the total quantity of products sold? Node

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

In the product table add one field like sellcounter and do following the operation.

After placing an order make one update query in product Table Like...

```
await productModel.updateAll({
          id: product.id
        }, {
          sellcounter: product.sellcounter + 1
        });
```

Above code is for loopback Node

Comment: You want to get count from another table and increment it by one ?

Comment: No, While Order gets confirmed Your product sellcounter will increase @Mayank

Comment: So once the new Order is created, you want to increment the sellcount of that product right? are these column exists in same model or different......If they exist in same use 'updateAttribute' method.

Comment: @RohitAmbre Both are different models Sellconter Column is in product table when order query get successfully run you can run sell counter query

Comment: ummm it seems like you'll have to `findOne` product from Product model for which order was placed and then call `updateAttribute ` method on the object......i'll update if I find any other way

Comment: @RohitAmbre Like Below

Comment: If Order gets confirmed then find ordered products from order then update product sell counter yes have used findOne

Comment: @AkibDahya, I have added answer to be clear about the flow, its a pseudo code so dont use it directly, It has syntax mistakes...accept and upvote if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea here is to increment the number of sales by one on a specific product.

To do so, you'll need to use the method `findOne` or `findById` to update the specific product.

The resulted code should look like this *(assuming that you have the product object with its id)*:

```js
const productToUpdate = await productModel.findById(product.id);
await productToUpdate.updateAttributes({ sellcounter: product.sellcounter + 1 });
```